# PHP List in multiple columns

Tags: php, list

i have one long list generated from a query, but i need to output to a maximum of 4 lists (4 columns) with a maximum of 17 results in each list (total max of 68) as there is a set height and width to fit this in, im new to php so im not sure where to start. I hope that makes sense!

```
<li class="dir">List title
        <?php
        // The following query gets all brands that appear in the mens categories and orders by manufacturer name
        $mens_categories_products_query = "SELECT * FROM `products_to_categories` `pc` ";
        $mens_categories_products_query .= "LEFT JOIN `products` `pr` ON `pc`.`products_id` = `pr`.`products_id` ";
        $mens_categories_products_query .= "LEFT JOIN `manufacturers` `mn` ON `pr`.`manufacturers_id` = `mn`.`manufacturers_id` ";
        $mens_categories_products_query .= "WHERE `pc`.`categories_id` IN (";
        $mens_categories_products_query .= substr($mens_categories_products_ids, 0, strlen($mens_categories_products_ids)-1);
        $mens_categories_products_query .= ") GROUP BY `pr`.`manufacturers_id` ORDER BY `mn`.`manufacturers_name`";
        //$mens_manufacturers_query = tep_db_query("SELECT * FROM `manufacturers` ORDER BY `manufacturers_name` ASC;");

        // Run the new query 
        $mens_manufacturers_query = tep_db_query($mens_categories_products_query);
        $mens_manufacturers_list = "";
        while ($mens_manufacturers = tep_db_fetch_array($mens_manufacturers_query)) {

            $mens_manufacturers_list .= '<li><a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, 'manufacturers_id=' . $mens_manufacturers['manufacturers_id']) . '">' . $mens_manufacturers['manufacturers_name'] . '</a></li>';

        }

        echo "<ul>$mens_manufacturers_list</ul>";
        ?>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
$i = 1;
print "<ul>";
while ($mens_manufacturers = tep_db_fetch_array($mens_manufacturers_query)) {
            if ($i % 17 == 1) { 
                print "<ul>";
            }
            if ($i == 68) {
                print '<li><a href="readmore.php">Read more</a></li>';
            }
            else {
                print '<li><a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, 'manufacturers_id=' . $mens_manufacturers['manufacturers_id']) . '">' . $mens_manufacturers['manufacturers_name'] . '</a></li>';
            }
            if ($i % 17 == 0) { 
                 print "</ul>";
            }
            $i++;    
}
```

With CSS something like

```
ul {
    width: 21%;
    float: left;
}
```

UPDATED:

Code updated to correct numbering loop on the first `<ul>`. Added 'read more' link on 68th entry.

Comment: thanks, at what point would i add this code in? im assuming under //Run the new query but im not sure what to leave in or replace?

Comment: Yes, that would be the right place. This would output four `<ul></ul>`'s inside `<li class="dir">` that you could then style to fit your container.

Comment: You could take out the lines from `//Run the new query` up to `echo "<ul>$mens_manufacturers_list</ul>";` as I wasn't using the $mens_manufacturers_list variable.

Comment: great thanks, stackoverflow is an awesome resource, im new here, much appreciated feedback!

Comment: Hope it's useful for you! If this answer works for you, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: But you'll probably want to test it first to make sure it works :)

Comment: ok im getting results using the first suggestion! just to add a spanner in the works i would like to max these entries to 67 and for number 68 add a more details link in the <li></li>

Comment: Hi, I've tested the code now and it should work :). I've also updated to include the 'read more' button.

Comment: thanks, i really appreciate this, im a jquery/css/html guy but php hurts my head, i like it though!

Answer (score 0):

try adding an icrement variable and at 17 rows add another ul

```
$i = 0;
$mens_manufacturers_list = '<ul>';
$dbresult = tep_db_fetch_array($mens_manufacturers_query);
while ($mens_manufacturers = $dbresult) {
    $i++;
    $mens_manufacturers_list .= '<li><a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, 'manufacturers_id=' . $mens_manufacturers['manufacturers_id']) . '">' . $mens_manufacturers['manufacturers_name'] . '</a></li>';

    if($i%17==0){
        $mens_manufacturers_list .= '</ul>';
    }
    if(count($dbresult) < $i){
        $mens_manufacturers_list .= '<ul>';
    }
}
echo $mens_manufacturers_list;
```

Comment: you can add after ``$i++`` another condition, ``if($i == 1){ $mens_manufacturers_list .= "<li>Brand name</li>"; } else ...``

Comment: Hi, im not having much luck as i think im not quite getting it right as in add the code, its coming back as invalid argument for this line: WARNING: INVALID ARGUMENT SUPPLIED FOR FOREACH() IN
The line is: foreach ($dbresult as $mens_manufacturers) {

Comment: thanks, what do i replace with "while" exactly - sorry im bad at php and need specifics!

Answer (score 0):

thorn, ive changed the code a little im wondering how i can get your updated code with the read more to work in this:

```
        <?php $i = 1;
        echo "<li class=\"dir\">BRANDS<ul>";
        $skate_manufacturers_query = tep_db_query($skate_categories_products_query);
        while ($skate_manufacturers = tep_db_fetch_array($skate_manufacturers_query)) {

        if ($i % 17 == 0) 
        echo "</ul></li><!-- start col --><li class=\"dir\">&nbsp;<ul>";
        echo '<li><a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, 'manufacturers_id=' . $skate_manufacturers['manufacturers_id']) . '">' . $skate_manufacturers['manufacturers_name'] . '</a></li>';
        if ($i % 18 == 0) 
        echo "<!-- end one col -->";
        $i++;    
        } ?>

    </ul> <!-- needs these added -->
</li>  <!-- needs these added -->
```

Comment: ok ive got it working, how do i get it to stop outputting results at 68, a maximum results sort of thing...